# Searching for available Apple Developer account names

Tags: search, accounts

I am about to set up a company but I have a suspicion another developer has taken the name that we would intend to trade under for a developer account.

We're setting up our business in the UK, and the official registration office (companies house) claims the name is available as far as 'the company' is concerned, but is there some way I can check if the Apple Developer account name will be available before actually forming the company? Will it be a problem or can we and this third party both trade under near-identical names? (for example fuzzy games and fuzzy-games).

Comment: Sorry bud. This type of question isn't covered. We don't deal with legalities of running a business. This also has no bearing on Apple related products.

Comment: looking over it, it's poorly worded which makes it sound more legal than it is. I just want to know how to search for apple dev account name availability. Can this be done?

Comment: What prevents you from just creating the account?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can pick **any** name as you like, as long as your company details shared with Apple are correct. And yes, they check everything before you get approved - took me a few weeks to fix the details with them because they've missed the "Inc."

Do you really want to change your future company name if the account is taken as Apple ID? There are many many many companies around with similar names, or near similar names.

Just take the name you had in mind, as long as your company details match there is nothing they can do to disapprove your Apple ID.

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't disclose other people's names to you when you sign up, so fill out the forms correctly and press submit.

You will make many mistakes in the first year of creating a business, most of which involve agonizing over things you can and will change later. If you corporate structure isn't set, my advice is to start with a personal developer account now and get to work. You can contact Apple Developer relations to change from a personal account to a corporate one mid-stream if needed before (and even after) putting your app up for public release.

You also will get notified if trademark infringement comes up, but again that is more a legal issue than something about how the store or iTunes connect account works.